# Keep elements displayed in fullscreen UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

Below is my design containing media element, play, pause, full window and seeker.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="VideosMediaElement" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Height="250" Width="355" Margin="0,20,0,0"
              BufferingProgressChanged="VideosMediaElement_BufferingProgressChanged"
              RealTimePlayback="True"
              />
<Grid x:Name="mediaGrid">
    <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="60" Background="Black"
            Opacity="0.1">
    </Border>
    <Image x:Name="PlayIcon" Source="Assets/Play-icon.png"
           Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           Margin="3,0,0,10" Visibility="Collapsed" Tapped="PlayIcon_Tapped">
    </Image>

    <Image x:Name="PauseIcon" Source="Assets/Pause.png"
           Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           Margin="3,0,0,10" Tapped="PauseIcon_Tapped" Visibility="Visible">
    </Image>

    <TextBlock x:Name="duration" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="43,0,0,20">
    </TextBlock>

    <ProgressBar x:Name="videoProgressBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                 Margin="15 0 10 25" Foreground="DarkBlue" Background="Gray"
                 Width="180" Height="10" Minimum="0"
                 Maximum="{Binding Path=NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds,
                                   Mode=TwoWay, 
                                   ElementName=VideosMediaElement}"
                 Value="{Binding Path=Position.TotalSeconds, Mode=TwoWay,
                                 ElementName=VideosMediaElement}"
                 Tapped="videoProgressBar_Tapped"
                 />

    <TextBlock x:Name="maximumDuration" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,40,20"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    </TextBlock>

    <Image x:Name="ExpandEnabled" Source="Assets/Fullscreen.png"
           Tapped="Zoom_Tapped" Height="35" Margin="0 0 3 10"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

[image: Rendering of the above design]

If I click the full window icon on the right hand side, the video shows as full window with play, pause, seeker and full window button.

```
VideosMediaElement.IsFullWindow = true;
```

```
<MediaElement x:Name="VideosMediaElement" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Height="300" Width="360"
              BufferingProgressChanged="VideosMediaElement_BufferingProgressChanged"
              AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
         <MediaTransportControls IsCompact="True" IsZoomButtonVisible="False"
                                 IsZoomEnabled="False"
                                 IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="True"
                                 IsPlaybackRateEnabled="True"
                                 />
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```

The video plays in full window, but play, pause and seeker are hiding when I set the `IsWindowFull` property. How to show those controls when the media element is in full window?

Comment: In this case, why not just use the default [TransportControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols.aspx) since you're not doing anything too custom it looks like anyway and would look cleaner?

Comment: thanks @ChrisW. It's working absolutely fine

Comment: Hi @ChrisW, i am facing a problem while using default Transportcontrols. I want to show the video in full window in landscape mode when user clicks maximize button. But, in that case none of the event was triggering. Is there a way to get that? Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which events? You mean buttons overlaying the video?

Comment: hi @ChrisW, i have added my code. As in the code i am using TrasportControls. It is working fine in portrait mode. But, my concern is when user clicks maximize button it should change into landscape mode in full window.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, then you're going to need to add code to that click event that forces the orientation to change via [DisplayOrientations enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayorientations), otherwise the result you see is expected if the device is being held as Portrait already. Perhaps this is worth a separate question since your original one appears answered by Grace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the Live Visual Tree to check your Layout in the run-time:
[image]

When a `MediaElement` enters into the `FullScreen` mode, `FullWindowMediaRoot` will host the `MeidiaElement` and your `mediaGrid` will not be shown in this time. One method is as @Chris W. said use the `TransportControls` of `MediaElement`, but this is not available in Windows 8.1 app, as you developed a windows phone 8.1 app, there is no such problem.

Since custom transport control is not supported in WP8.1, for windows phone 8.1 app, you can manually set the `Width` and `Height` of `MediaElement` to App's size for example like this:

```
VideosMediaElement.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
VideosMediaElement.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
```

Since the app runs on WP8.1 as full screen mode, this method will also make the `MediaElement` looks like it is in full screen mode. And when you want to "exit from full screen mode", you can just reset the `Height` and `Width` properties.

Comment: HI Grace. Thanks for your reply. Now, i am developing my app in Windows 10, so i have used TransportControls. And in WP8.1, even if we specify Width and Height like the way u mention i am getting the same problem.

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala, when developing UWP app, we can [Create custom transport controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls), for WP8.1, when setting `Width` and `Height`, you don't need to set  `VideosMediaElement.IsFullWindow = true;`, otherwise the same problem will happen.