# How to sync ui to full screen or compact mode using MediaPlayerElement

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, uwp-xaml

I'm using `MediaPlayerElement`, when my app window in normal size, I have a Button and a TextBox on the  `MediaPlayerElement`. But when I click fullscreen or compact button to enter fullscreen or compact mode, they disappeared.

How to show them in full screen or compact mode?

A helpfull repo is [here](https://github.com/hupo376787/MediaElementSoundBug.git), sync the TextBox to fullscreen.

[image]

Comment: This reply may [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691534/7254781).

Comment: It seems I need to write the controls in my own MediaTransportControls style, and then apply to MediaPlayerElement. I'll try. Thx.

Comment: Great, If you have any updates please post below.

Comment: Hi, Nico. I found out custom MediaTransportControls only affect the control bar area. I want to place a logo on the right-top of the MediaPlayerElement. So the upper reply doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you could custom your `MediaTransportControls` and found `ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border` in the style. Then add your element under the that border.

**For example**

```
<Border x:Name="ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            FontSize="25"
            Foreground="Red"
            Text="This is title"
            />
        <Grid
            x:Name="ControlPanelGrid"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
......
```

I add the title TextBlock into the style.

Comment: Wow, it works. But I did something different. Since ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border maybe disappear when mouse pointer stay still, this will cause my stuff disappear. So I put my stuff outside of the ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border, thus my stuff will always show on top.