# How to control customized MediaTransportControls?

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, uwp-xaml

I'm using `MediaPlayerElement`, and added an `Image` on the right-top of the player, following my another so: [How to sync ui to full screen or compact mode using MediaPlayerElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972131/how-to-sync-ui-to-full-screen-or-compact-mode-using-mediaplayerelement/57989444#57989444).

```
<Image
     x:Name="Image_CPLOGO" Width="160" Height="80" Margin="36"
     HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
     Source="{TemplateBinding CPLogo}"/>
```

And I have custom my own `MediaTransportControls` following [Customize the transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls#customize-the-transport-controls)

```
<MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
    <controls:CustomMediaTransportControls
        Style="{StaticResource ViuMediaTransportControls}"
        x:Name="MediaTransportControls_Custom">
    </controls:CustomMediaTransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
```

Then in CustomMediaTransportControls.cs, I wrote

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CPLogoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CPLogo", typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public ImageSource CPLogo
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(CPLogoProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CPLogoProperty, value); }
        }
```

At last, I wrote code to set Image:

```
MediaTransportControls_Custom.CPLogo = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ccd4648ac12e04ad93a5c3a32911383a?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"));
```

But this doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you apply your `CustonMediaTransportControl` to your `MediaTransportControls` style?

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomMediaTransportControls">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsTextScaleFactorEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomMediaTransportControls">
```